# ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 198 but expected 300 for dimension 1 of input 175

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am using tensorflow lite for object detection specifically the SSDLite-MobileNet-v2 object detection model from google. Along with object detection I am also performing color detection of that particular object using opencv.For that I am referring to this tutorial on youtube.

[Simple color detection](https://youtu.be/t71sQ6WY7L4)

Here first the frame read is converted into HSV format and the the HSV value of a pixel at the center of the object bounding box is found out and the color is estimated

For object detection I'm referring to the following GitHub code--
https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi

The code for object and color detection:-

```
class VideoStream:
"""Camera object that controls video streaming from the Picamera"""
    def __init__(self,resolution=(640,480),framerate=30):
        ## Initialize the PiCamera and the camera image stream
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        ret = self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'))
        ret = self.stream.set(3,resolution[0])
        ret = self.stream.set(4,resolution[1])
        
        ## Read first frame from the stream
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

        ## Variable to control when the camera is stopped
        self.stopped = False

    def start(self):
        ##Start the thread that reads frames from the video stream
        Thread(target=self.update,args=()).start()
        return self

    def update(self):
        ## Keep looping indefinitely until the thread is stopped
        while True:
            ## If the camera is stopped, stop the thread
            if self.stopped:
                ## Close camera resources
                self.stream.release()
                return

            ##Otherwise, grab the next frame from the stream
            (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

    def read(self):
    ## Return the most recent frame
        return self.frame

    def stop(self):
    ## Indicate that the camera and thread should be stopped
        self.stopped = True
## Define and parse input arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--modeldir', help='Folder the .tflite file is located in',
                    required=True)
parser.add_argument('--graph', help='Name of the .tflite file, if different than detect.tflite',
                    default='detect.tflite')
parser.add_argument('--labels', help='Name of the labelmap file, if different than labelmap.txt',
                    default='labelmap.txt')
parser.add_argument('--threshold', help='Minimum confidence threshold for displaying detected objects',
                    default=0.5)
parser.add_argument('--resolution', help='Desired webcam resolution in WxH. If the webcam does not support the resolution entered, errors may occur.',
                    default='1280x720')
parser.add_argument('--edgetpu', help='Use Coral Edge TPU Accelerator to speed up detection',
                    action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

MODEL_NAME = args.modeldir
GRAPH_NAME = args.graph
LABELMAP_NAME = args.labels
min_conf_threshold = float(args.threshold)
resW, resH = args.resolution.split('x')
imW, imH = int(resW), int(resH)
use_TPU = args.edgetpu

## Import TensorFlow libraries
## If tflite_runtime is installed, import interpreter from tflite_runtime, else import from regular tensorflow
## If using Coral Edge TPU, import the load_delegate library
pkg = importlib.util.find_spec('tflite_runtime')
if pkg:
    from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter
    if use_TPU:
        from tflite_runtime.interpreter import load_delegate
else:
    from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import Interpreter
    if use_TPU:
        from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import load_delegate

## If using Edge TPU, assign filename for Edge TPU model
if use_TPU:
    # If user has specified the name of the .tflite file, use that name, otherwise use default 'edgetpu.tflite'
    if (GRAPH_NAME == 'detect.tflite'):
        GRAPH_NAME = 'edgetpu.tflite'       

## Get path to current working directory
CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

## Path to .tflite file, which contains the model that is used for object detection
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,GRAPH_NAME)

## Path to label map file
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,LABELMAP_NAME)

## Load the label map
with open(PATH_TO_LABELS, 'r') as f:
    labels = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

## Have to do a weird fix for label map if using the COCO "starter model" from
## https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview
## First label is '???', which has to be removed.
if labels[0] == '???':
    del(labels[0])

## Load the Tensorflow Lite model.
## If using Edge TPU, use special load_delegate argument
if use_TPU:
    interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT,
                              experimental_delegates=[load_delegate('libedgetpu.so.1.0')])
    print(PATH_TO_CKPT)
else:
    interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT)

interpreter.allocate_tensors()

## Get model details
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
height = input_details[0]['shape'][1]
width = input_details[0]['shape'][2]

floating_model = (input_details[0]['dtype'] == np.float32)

input_mean = 127.5
input_std = 127.5

## Initialize frame rate calculation
frame_rate_calc = 1
freq = cv2.getTickFrequency()

## Initialize video stream
videostream = VideoStream(resolution=(imW,imH),framerate=30).start()
time.sleep(1)
while True:

    ## Start timer (for calculating frame rate)
    t1 = cv2.getTickCount()

    ## Grab frame from video stream
    frame1 = videostream.read()

    ## Acquire frame and resize to expected shape [1xHxWx3]
    frame = frame1.copy()
    frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame_rgb, (width, height))
    input_data = np.expand_dims(frame_resized, axis=0)

    ## Normalize pixel values if using a floating model (i.e. if model is non-quantized)
    if floating_model:
        input_data = (np.float32(input_data) - input_mean) / input_std

    ## Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'],input_data)
    interpreter.invoke()

    ## Retrieve detection results
    boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])[0] ## Bounding box coordinates of detected objects
    classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])[0] ## Class index of detected objects
    scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index'])[0] ## Confidence of detected objects
    ##num = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[3]['index'])[0]  # Total number of detected 
    ## Loop over all detections and draw detection box if confidence is above minimum threshold
    for i in range(len(scores)):
        if ((scores[i] > min_conf_threshold) and (scores[i] <= 1.0)):

            ## Get bounding box coordinates and draw box
            ## Interpreter can return coordinates that are outside of image dimensions, need to force them to be within image using max() and min()
            ymin = int(max(1,(boxes[i][0] * imH)))
            xmin = int(max(1,(boxes[i][1] * imW)))
            ymax = int(min(imH,(boxes[i][2] * imH)))
            xmax = int(min(imW,(boxes[i][3] * imW)))
            ## print(ymin,xmin,ymax,xmax)
            
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin,ymin), (xmax,ymax), (10, 255, 0), 2)

            ## Draw label
            object_name = labels[int(classes[i])] 
            print(object_name)

            ##colour detection
            hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            height, width=(ymax-ymin),(xmax-xmin) 

            cx = int(width / 2)
            cy = int(height / 2)

            ## Pick pixel value
            pixel_center = hsv_frame[cy+ymin, cx+xmin]
            hue_value = pixel_center[0]
            sat_value = pixel_center[1]
            val_value = pixel_center[2]
            print(hue_value,sat_value,val_value)
            color = "Undefined"
            if hue_value>166 and val_value<95:
                color="black"
            elif hue_value < 5: 
                color = "RED"
            elif hue_value < 22:
                color = "ORANGE"
            elif hue_value < 33:
                color = "YELLOW"
            elif hue_value < 67:
                color = "GREEN"
            elif hue_value < 117:
                color = "BLUE"
            elif hue_value < 144:
                color = "VIOLET"
            elif hue_value < 160:
                color = "PINK"
            else:
                color = "RED"
            print(color)



            label = '%s: %d%%' % (object_name, int(scores[i]*100)) ## Example: 'person: 72%'
            labelSize, baseLine = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, 2) ## Get font size
            label_ymin = max(ymin, labelSize[1] + 10) ## Make sure not to draw label too close to top of window
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, label_ymin-labelSize[1]-10), (xmin+labelSize[0], label_ymin+baseLine-10), (255, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED) ## Draw white box to put label text in
            cv2.putText(frame, label, (xmin, label_ymin-7), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 0), 2) ## Draw label text

    ## Draw framerate in corner of frame
    cv2.putText(frame,'FPS: {0:.2f}'.format(frame_rate_calc),(30,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(255,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

    ## All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
    cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)

    

    ## Press 'q' to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

## Clean up
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
videostream.stop()
```

I am new to tensorflow lite. When I run this code it runs perfectly for the first iteration of the while loop and outputs-- (cup and the color orange) but then i get this error.

```
cup
20 215 197
ORANGE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\download\TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi-master\TFLite_detection_webcam.py", line 188, 
in <module>
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'],input_data)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\interpreter.py", line 705, in set_tensor
    self._interpreter.SetTensor(tensor_index, value)
ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 198 but expected 300 for dimension 1 of input 175.
```

But if I remove the color detection code completely from the while loop (Colour detection code is mentioned below). It runs without any error and returns the object name

Color detection code in while loop:-

```
  ##colour detection
            hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            height, width=(ymax-ymin),(xmax-xmin) 

            cx = int(width / 2)
            cy = int(height / 2)

            ## Pick pixel value
            pixel_center = hsv_frame[cy+ymin, cx+xmin]
            hue_value = pixel_center[0]
            sat_value = pixel_center[1]
            val_value = pixel_center[2]
            print(hue_value,sat_value,val_value)
            color = "Undefined"
            if hue_value>166 and val_value<95:
                color="black"
            elif hue_value < 5: 
                color = "RED"
            elif hue_value < 22:
                color = "ORANGE"
            elif hue_value < 33:
                color = "YELLOW"
            elif hue_value < 67:
                color = "GREEN"
            elif hue_value < 117:
                color = "BLUE"
            elif hue_value < 144:
                color = "VIOLET"
            elif hue_value < 160:
                color = "PINK"
            else:
                color = "RED"
        print(color)
```

how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error is suggesting that the dimensions are wrong. 
The cause is that you overwrite the variables width, height with the output dimensions of the network which is not same as input_dimensions of the network hence it breaks. 
**Solution** Change the name of variable width, height in your color detection code.